# Is there a name to define "conferences are publications" fields?

Tags: discussion, tags

When asking for clarifications in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95163/is-it-okay-to-use-same-figures-in-different-papers), it occurred to me that, fundamentally, many customs pertaining conference abstracts depend actually on a single yes-no bit: there are some fields where conference abstracts are considered publications (engineering, computer science...), and some fields where they are not (mathematics, and, if I understand correctly, chemistry, biology, most fields within the humanities).

1. Is this classification correct?
2. Does this subdivision make sense?
3. Is there a word or an expression to distinguish these two areas of academia? For instance, something that we can turn into a tag?

Comment: At least questions 1 (in the sense of: “is this actually binary”?) and the first part of question 3 are something that you can ask on the main site. Question 2 depends on what you want to achieve with this question. If it is a tag and the answer to question 1 is *yes,* then *yes.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks, I have replaced "liberal arts". I have considered asking #1 on main, but I don't think it is a good fit: as it happens every time we try to divide something in two categories, the subdivision makes sense only with a specific purpose in mind: in this case my purpose is identifying a large set of questions whose answers apply indistinctly to all "conferences-are-publications" fields or to all "conferences-are-not-publications" fields, but not to the other, and state this appropriately to avoid repetition and confusion. With this stated purpose, it's a question for meta.

Comment: *every time we try to divide something in two categories, the subdivision makes sense only with a specific purpose in mind* – Sure, but we don’t have to ask a *yes or no* question. Rather, the interesting question is whether there are any grey zones or there is a third way, because that’s something we might need to take into account when creating such tags. Also, even though motivated through a self-servicing purpose, it would be fit for the main site as it is a request for information that is valid and relevant beyond this site. Anyway, if you don’t want to ask the question, I would do it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Please go ahead. I wouldn't know how to formulate this question properly, myself.

Comment: When you say publication, do you really mean peer-reviewed abstracts?

Comment: Abstracts or proceedings?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Relevant existing question: [Is the status of conference publications in Computer Science really absolutely unique?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/40783/7734)

Comment: And I finally asked: [Conferences as publication venues – black and white or is there a grey or third way?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/95306/7734).

Answer (score 6):

Going by the [current outcome of my question-turned-survey on what different treatments of conferences exist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/95306/7734), I suggest not to categorise questions by fields or even conferences but by the treatment of the submissions in question.

I therefore suggest to introduce a tag [conference-publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conference-publications) (or similar) for questions concerning submissions to conferences which are treated as (serious) publications. Thus:

- Questions about general peer-reviewing, paper writing, or authorship that apply to both journals and conferences shall be tagged as before.
- Questions about giving presentations, posters, chairing, and answering questions that apply to both kinds of conferences shall be tagged as before.
- Questions that are specific to journals shall be tagged with [journals](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/journals) (as before).
- Questions that are specific to conference submissions treated as publications shall be tagged [conference-publications](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conference-publications).
- Questions about submissions to conferences that are not treated as publications should just be tagged with [conferences](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conferences) (as before). While we could have a specific tag for those, I doubt that it will be of any use (hardly anybody will use it for searching; askers won’t even know that this could be a reason to tag a question; …).

Should this suggestion be accepted, we should organise how we apply this tag to old questions, as there will be many.

Comment: "Proceedings" is another good option for the name of your suggested tag, probably.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I disagree. In many fields proceedings are treated quite differently and submission to the proceedings is independent from submissions to the conference. See also the last paragraph of [my question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95306/7734) as well as [this deleted non-answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/95313/7734).

Comment: I see, I agree with you.